# How to query EntryQuery for multiple sections with varying types

Tags: craft3, api

I think the best way to pose this question is by giving an example:

Given a variable $query of type craft\elements\db\EntryQuery, I'd like to get entries from 2 different sections: "people" and "news". Of the entries from the "people" section, I only want ones with entry type "Employees". How would I set this up so that the "type" filter only applies to 1 section? If I were querying them individually, they would look like this:

```
$query->section('people')->type('Employees');
$query->section('insights');
```

How can I do this in 1 query? Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, could I create 2 queries and combine them somehow? I need to preserve it as a query, so I can't just use .all() and merge the arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can achieve this in one query.

The easiest solution I can think of to your problem requires 3 queries:

```
{% set peopleIds = craft.entries().section('people').type('Employees').ids() %}
{% set insightIds = craft.entries().section('insights').ids() %}
{% set query = craft.entries().id(peopleIds|merge(insightIds))
```

The first 2 queries are executed and return the ids of the matching entries. You can then create  your EntryQuery using the ids as the only criterion.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @nstCactus, that's a great idea! Just for anyone looking for the PHP equivalent:

```
$peopleIds = \craft\elements\Entry::find()->section('people')->type('Employees')->ids();
$insightIds = \craft\elements\Entry::find()->section('insights')->ids();
$query->id(array_merge($peopleIds, $insightsIds));
```